# XGBClassifier fails when I pass early_stopping_rounds

Tags: python, jupyter, xgboost

I am using `xgboost` in the following way:

```
from xgboost import XGBClassifier
clf = XGBClassifier()
clf = clf.fit(df_train, df_train_labels, verbose=True)
```

This works well. However, if I add an `early_stopping_rounds` parameter, like this:

```
clf = clf.fit(df_train, df_train_labels, early_stopping_rounds=10, verbose=True)
```

I get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-786925228ae5> in <module>()
      9 
     10 
---> 11 clf = clf.fit(df_train, df_train_labels, early_stopping_rounds=10, verbose=True)
     12 print("after fit")
     13 prediction = np.exp(clf.predict(df_test))

~/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xgboost/sklearn.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight, eval_set, eval_metric, early_stopping_rounds, verbose)
    443                               early_stopping_rounds=early_stopping_rounds,
    444                               evals_result=evals_result, obj=obj, feval=feval,
--> 445                               verbose_eval=verbose)
    446 
    447         self.objective = xgb_options["objective"]

~/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xgboost/training.py in train(params, dtrain, num_boost_round, evals, obj, feval, maximize, early_stopping_rounds, evals_result, verbose_eval, learning_rates, xgb_model, callbacks)
    203                            evals=evals,
    204                            obj=obj, feval=feval,
--> 205                            xgb_model=xgb_model, callbacks=callbacks)
    206 
    207 

~/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xgboost/training.py in _train_internal(params, dtrain, num_boost_round, evals, obj, feval, xgb_model, callbacks)
     99                                end_iteration=num_boost_round,
    100                                rank=rank,
--> 101                                evaluation_result_list=evaluation_result_list))
    102         except EarlyStopException:
    103             break

~/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xgboost/callback.py in callback(env)
    190     def callback(env):
    191         """internal function"""
--> 192         score = env.evaluation_result_list[-1][1]
    193         if len(state) == 0:
    194             init(env)

IndexError: list index out of range
```

I looked this up and I saw that the `fit` method can be passed a multitude of parameters, so I don't believe that the fact that I added `early_stopping_rounds` should cause problems.

Any idea what could be the cause of this error?

Answer (score 9):

The reason for this error is that you haven't specified an eval_set, which xgboost uses to determine when to stop for early-stopping.

See the docs for the *fit* method [here](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html#module-xgboost.sklearn).

> eval_set (list, optional) – A list of (X, y) tuple pairs to use as a validation set for early-stopping

For example, if you've split your data into train and test sets, you would use something along these lines:

```
eval_set = [(X_test, y_test)]

clf = clf.fit(df_train,
              df_train_labels,
              eval_set=eval_set,
              early_stopping_rounds=10,
              verbose=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

One reason other than Chris gave is that `early_stopping_rounds`  is used when we want to find the correct value of `n_estimators` (which is nothing but how many times the modeling cycle happens). You haven't specified the `n_estimators` parameter in your model. You should always specify both the parameters in XGB models.